# How to Call Javascript Messagebox from Code behind without Postback

Tags: c#, javascript

How i can Call Javascript Messagebox from Code behind C# without Postback ?

I have one method in C# Codebehind if that returns False i should show a messagebox on UI without posting back.
I tried using

```
if (bValidate == false)
{
     ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,typeof(Page), "pro", "alert('SMTP Server is Down. Please try again');",true);
}
```

But page posted back.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using update panels?

Comment: So just change the `ScriptManager` to the `ClientScriptManager` :)

Comment: can you please describe how to use ClientScriptManager in this case ?

Comment: Sure, there is a method `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` like you did with the ScriptManager.

Comment: ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
                cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "CIS", "alert('SMTP Server is Down. Please try again');");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61342/discussion-between-user662285-and-gustavodidomenico).

Comment: I am using this as suggested by you but now also page gets postback..

Comment: ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
                    cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CIS", "alert('SMTP Server is Down. Please try again');",true);

Comment: Let me do an example for you. Just need some time.

Comment: Any body can help me out using javascript as well...i get value from server side...on button click...if that value is false i need to show alert box...Page should not get refreshed or postback..

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It is just clear now. You must prevent the post back in the button click or after the click inside de alert?